# Emacs bad font rendering under Windows

Tags: emacs, fonts

After some googling I found, that people recomment font Inconsolata for programming in Emacs. I installed it on Windows and Linux from here:

http://www.levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html

Here are the screenshots of the same text 1 - Linux, 2 - Windows XP SP3:

[image: Linux]

[image: Windows]

Under Windows the font is thin, unclear and is uncomfortable for reading. Is it possible to make it render it as well as on Linux?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download and install Inconsolata.ttf font and install it instead of otf:

http://googlefontdirectory.googlecode.com/hg-history/fffda675769720a297f4d239e7065f751bbe655f/inconsolata/Inconsolata.ttf

It will be rendered smoothly on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Just use Consolas, it's hands down the best monospace font to use on Windows ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgmJi.png)).

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 115 :family "Consolas")
```

Answer (score 1):

My favorite is Source Code Pro (https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro/releases/tag/1.017R) - again make sure to use `ttf`.

Comment: Thx, will try the font you suggested

Answer (score 0):

You can run the Cygwin version, using X11.  It should give you the exact same output as under GNU/Linux in this respect.